# Powershell Get-Counter not reporting

Tags: windows, powershell

Using the cmdlet:

```
Get-Counter -ComputerName $server '\Processor(*)\% Processor Time'
```

-or just-

```
Get-Counter -ComputerName $server
```

I get the error message:

```
get-counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-counter -ComputerName '********' '\Processor(*)\% Processor Time ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

I have this running correctly on 3 other nearly identical Windows [2000] Servers, but it fails to report on this one. The VM has been rebooted several times. Also, the server statistics are reporting correctly to the VM manager.

Any idea what *Get-Counter* is trying to communicate with and why it says that the specified object is not found?

Comment: Are you sure you want to supp an OS that is dead?

Comment: @djdomi It is for monitoring a legacy system that has no upgrade path.

Comment: I belive that in case of w2k will be one issue: no one use it anymore even a company thati supported has migrated away the last server within a machine. I would go further and suggest a upgrade with the vendor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a definitive answer for Windows Server 2000 will be a challenge, but the error sounds exactly like what is described in a commonly-used article: "[Manually rebuild performance counters for Windows Server 2008 64 bit or Windows Server 2008 R2 systems](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/manually-rebuild-performance-counters)" and I would expect the solution to be the same.

Generally, when using performance counters results in the "object not found" error, that indicates one or more performance counters are broken and need to be rebuilt.

Quoting the article, in case links die:

**1. Check the registry to make sure the counter you want to use is not disabled.**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\%servicename%\Performance
```

- A value of 1 means the counter is disabled.
- A value of 2 means the 32-bit counter is disabled.
- A value of 4 means the 64-bit counter is disabled.

**2. Rebuild the counters:**

```
cd c:\windows\system32
lodctr /R
cd c:\windows\sysWOW64
lodctr /R
```

**3. Resync the counters with the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI):**

```
WINMGMT.EXE /RESYNCPERF
```

**4. Stop and restart the Performance Logs and Alerts service.**

**5. Stop and restart the Windows Management Instrumentation service.**

**6. Create a new Data Collector Set (don't use an existing Data Collector Set).**

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I had to fix a couple registry values and rebuild the counters to get it working.  Also, I used this:  https://documentation.red-gate.com/amp7/troubleshooting/unexpected-behavior-and-technical-questions/rebuilding-performance-counters